How does Android Media3 retain a recall function in the media playback bar after the app is closed in the background?
I have now implemented music playback, but the media playback bar will be closed together after the application is closed. I don't want it to close entirely, but I can retain a play button that can evoke the application, similar to the one in the picture below.
enter image description here
My current mediaSession is like this
class ExampleLibraryPlaybackService : MediaLibraryService() {

    private var exoPlayer: ExoPlayer? = null
    private var mediaSession: MediaLibrarySession? = null
    @OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        setMediaNotificationProvider(ExampleMediaNotificationProvider(this))
        val exoPlayerBuilder = ExoPlayer.Builder(this)
        exoPlayer = exoPlayerBuilder.build()
        val commandButtonExtras = Bundle()
        commandButtonExtras.putInt(
            DefaultMediaNotificationProvider.COMMAND_KEY_COMPACT_VIEW_INDEX,
            0
        )
        val sessionCommand = SessionCommand(SAVE_TO_FAVORITES, Bundle.EMPTY)
        val favoriteButton =
            CommandButton.Builder()
                .setEnabled(true)
                .setDisplayName("favorites")
                .setExtras(commandButtonExtras)
                .setIconResId(R.drawable.favorite)
                .setSessionCommand(sessionCommand)
                .build()

        val intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)
        intent?.putExtra("DESTINATION", "player")
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

        mediaSession =
            MediaLibrarySession.Builder(
                this,
                exoPlayer!!,
                object : MediaLibrarySession.Callback {
                  //......
                    
                })
                .setCustomLayout(ImmutableList.of(favoriteButton))
                .setSessionActivity(pendingIntent)
                .build()

    }
    override fun onDestroy() {
        exoPlayer?.stop()
        exoPlayer?.release()
        exoPlayer = null
        mediaSession?.release()
        mediaSession = null
        CacheController.release()

        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onGetSession(controllerInfo: MediaSession.ControllerInfo): MediaLibrarySession? {
        return mediaSession
    }
}

